# Simple Command Line calculator

Tags: java

I have written a code for a command-line calculator in Java but I can't understand the errors which are not allowing it to compile

```
public class Calculator{
public static void main(String[] args){

int numOne = args[0];
int numTwo = args[1];

add(numOne, numTwo) {
    result = numOne + numTwo;
    System.out.println("{numOne} + {numTwo} = {result}");
}

subtract(numOne, numTwo) {
    result = numOne - numTwo;
    System.out.println("{numOne} - {numTwo} = {result}");
}

multiply(numOne, numTwo) {
    result = numOne * numTwo;
    System.out.println("{numOne} * {numTwo} = {result}");
}

divide(numOne, numTwo) {
    result = numOne / numTwo;
    System.out.println("{numOne} / {numTwo} = {result}");
}
}
}
```

Comment: what exactly are the errors? Please edit your post and add them in detail

Comment: Maybe you should start by reading a good [Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Comment: This is full of errors, it's not even close to being Java - I don't know where to start

Comment: @giddy for starters, he has some kind of functions with strange signatures in his main method. 2nd he uses println without `System.out` ... etc.

Comment: @cularis yea now i'm actually looking at the code, I just glanced the question in a few secs and posted my comment! :P

Comment: @cularis I will add the System.out now, can you please help me in knowing what else to fix, I think i don't quite understand method declaration. Please excuse me I am a n00b in java

Comment: @Cipher I don't think us answering this question will help you that much. It would be much more useful to read up a bit on some basic Java syntax. The Oracle Java Tutorial (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) is a great place to start. Good luck!

Comment: @dlev thanks but I am not very good at learning from reading, I learn by trial and error better, I've fixed up the code a little bit, Now I only get 4 errors

Comment: @Cipher The tutorial *includes* lots of doing as well! I understand the desire to just get going, but doing so without at least a little bit of a foundation can make the process slower overall. You know how you learn best, of course, so do what you must.

Comment: @dlev thanks very much mate, I will proceed with the tutorials

Answer (score 3):

The translation to java of your code is:

```
public class Calculator {

  public static void add(int numOne, int numTwo) {
    int result = numOne + numTwo;
    System.out.println(numOne + " + " + numTwo + " = " + result);
  }

  public static void subtract(int numOne, int numTwo) {
    int result = numOne - numTwo;
    System.out.println(numOne + " - " + numTwo + " = " + result);
  }

  public static void multiply(int numOne, int numTwo) {
    int result = numOne * numTwo;
    System.out.println(numOne + " * " + numTwo + " = " + result);
  }

  public static void divide(int numOne, int numTwo) {
    int result = numOne / numTwo;
    System.out.println(numOne + " / " + numTwo + " = " + result);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numOne = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int numTwo = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    add(numOne, numTwo);
    subtract(numOne, numTwo);
    multiply(numOne, numTwo);
    divide(numOne, numTwo);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sadly, this is likely to receive the green check. You have given this man a fish.

Comment: Thanks very much, Now I understood everything

Comment: @dlev no worries man, I now understand that I have to declare methods outside of the main class then call them from main, I understand how to retrieve the arguments and assign them to a variable

Comment: @Cipher Then you're well on your way. Enjoy learning a pretty sweet language.

Comment: That was a little help, clearly he knows how to program in another language; and it took two minutes to correct. we know that with the example he still have to "Enjoy learning a pretty sweet language" I agree

Comment: @vhtellez I used t know a little C++ but that was over 5 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define methods inside your main method, so this is most likely one of your first programs in Java.  Nothing wrong with that, but this makes you an example of the target audience for most introductory texts for programming in Java (if you do not have a teacher).

The Oracle Java Tutorial is quite nice.  You may want to start at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Answer (score 1):

args[] is a String[]. You can not assign its members directly into int.

You should use Integer.parseInt(String) to get its representation as int.

Also. there is no "println()". You probably mean System.out.println(String). And in the parameters there is no "field sustitution" (as is C printf), but you need to mount the expression:

```
 System.out.println(numOne + " / " + numTwo + " = " + result);
```

(here + is the concatenation operator, as it involves Strings)

Last (that I can see at first glance), you must define the functions that you call outside of main (but inside a class). Also you need either to declare them static (as main) or create a new object of this class in order to access them from main().

If after all of that it still does not compile, post the compile error messages.

Comment: I have edited the code, I used System.out and now I am trying to understand the other stuff that you wrote

Comment: Seeing all the errors in the code my guess is that you are going too fast and skipping steps... Take the advice of some of the people here and get a Java tutorial and begin with simpler ("Hello world") examples.